# TypeError jQuery timepicker is not a function on test

Tags: jquery, reactjs, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

I'm building a test using `Mocha` and `Chai` for my `ReactJS` components. Basically I have this structure for my components:

- ScheduleApp

  - ScheduleForm

Under my `ScheduleForm` I'm using this `jQuery` plugin [bootstrap-timepicker](https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker). I'm using another plugin called `bootstrap-datepicker` and it is running just fine notice the `componentDidMount` on my `ScheduleForm`.

```
// ScheduleForm.jsx Component
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import datepicker from 'bootstrap-datepicker';
import timepicker from 'bootstrap-timepicker';

export default class ScheduleForm extends React.Component {
    handleChange() {
        // Some code to handle the onChange event
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        jQuery(this.refs.startDate).datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        }).on("changeDate", function(e) {
            this.onStartDateChange(e);
        }.bind(this));

        jQuery(this.refs.startTime).timepicker({
            defaultTime: '8:00 AM',
            snapToStep: false
        }).on('changeTime.timepicker', function(e) {
            this.onStartTimeChange(e);
        }.bind(this));

        jQuery(this.refs.endTime).timepicker({
            defaultTime: '2:00 PM',
            snapToStep: false
        }).on('changeTime.timepicker', function(e) {
            this.onEndTimeChange(e);
        }.bind(this));
    }

    render() {
        <div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Start Date</label>
              <input className="form-control" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} ref="startDate" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Start Time</label>
              <input className="form-control" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} ref="startTime" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>End Time</label>
              <input className="form-control" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} ref="endTime" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Here's my parent component:

```
// ScheduleApp.jsx Component
import React from 'react';
import ScheduleForm from './schedule-form.jsx';

export default class ScheduleApp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            startTime: '8:00 AM',
            endTime: '2:00 PM'
        }
    }

    handleStartTimeChange(startTime) {
        this.setState({
            startTime: startTime
        });
    }

    handleEndTimeChange(endTime) {
        this.setState({
            endTime: endTime
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
                    <ScheduleForm
                            handleStartTimeChange={this.handleStartTimeChange.bind(this)}
                            handleEndTimeChange={this.handleEndTimeChange.bind(this)}
                            startTime={this.state.startTime}
                            endTime={this.state.endTime} />
                </div>
    }
}
```

Now here is my test spec for this component:

```
// test.spec.js
import React from 'react';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import ScheduleApp from '../src/components/schedule-app.jsx';
import ScheduleForm from '../src/components/schedule-form.jsx';

describe('<ScheduleApp/>', function() {
  it('contains 1 <ScheduleForm/> component', function() {
    const wrapper = mount(<ScheduleApp />);
    expect(wrapper.find(ScheduleForm)).to.have.length(1);
  });
});
```

Here is my `jsdom` file:

```
if (!global.document) {
  try {
    const jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom; // could throw

    const exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

    global.document = jsdom('');
    global.window = document.defaultView;
    Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
      if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
        exposedProperties.push(property);
        global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
      }
    });

    global.navigator = {
      userAgent: 'node.js',
    };
  } catch (e) {
    // jsdom is not supported...
  }
}
```

After running my test I get this error `TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).timepicker is not a function`. I can load this field fine without problem on my browser but with my test spec it throws out an error for the `timepicker` plugin and it's running ok with the `datepicker`.

Also if it's worth noting, `bootstrap-datepicker` and `bootstrap-timepicker` use the same jQuery and only `bootstrap-timepicker` requires `window` and `document` in its function parameter, like so:

```
(function($, window, document) {
}())
```

Also, is there a way to find out where the `jQuery` plugin is failing? This would have been really easy if I it shows it on the logs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to import jQuery for your spec as it uses a global.

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I've already tried that before and still throws out the same error. :( Both `bootstrap-datepicker` and `bootstrap-timepicker` use the same jQuery but only `bootstrap-timepicker` throws out an error.

Comment: Did u try importing the plugins as well?

Comment: Adding jQuery to window will also help.